# Aerogear unifiedpush node js client alias criteria is not working

Tags: node.js, push-notification, openshift, aerogear

I am running the following code for sending push message to only one device using 'alias' but message being sent to all installations, what could be wrong, can anybody help please?

Here is the code:

```
var agSender = require( "./lib/unifiedpush-node-sender" ),
    message,
    settings,
    options;

//Send a Message
settings = require( "./settings.json" );

message = {
    alert: "Hello AG Test"    
};

options = {
    config: {
        ttl: 3600,
    },
    criteria: {
        alias: ["xyz123@gmail.com"]
    }
};

agSender.Sender( settings ).send( message, options )
    .on( "success", function( response ) {
        console.log( "success called", response );
    })
    .on( "error", function( err ) {
        console.log( err );
    });
```

output:
success called Job submitted

Comment: have you checked the logs on the aerogear server?

Comment: Yes I checked, message received for all installations

Comment: what version of the sender are you using.   Also,  can you make sure that on your UnifiedPush Server, the installations in question do have separate alias's

Comment: We are using version 2.0, yes alias setting being added to Installations. Java Sender able to send properly

Comment: there isn't actually a version 2.0 for the node version.  latest on npm is 0.8.0-beta1. What version of the push server are you using,   I've created this JIRA issue,  https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AGPUSH-1459  to track it.

Comment: Yes, we are using latest npm is 0.8.0-beta1, with git repo: https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-unifiedpush-nodejs-client

Answer (score 0):

You might have a version mismatch.  The 1.0.x version of the UnifiedPush Server needs the 0.7.x series of the Node sender.

If you are using the 1.1.x series of the Unified Push server, then use the 0.8.x version

Comment: Do you know how I can get an older version like 0.12?

Comment: npm install unified-push-node@0.12.0  or whatever version you need